# Hosting Static sites via EC2 ELB and Cloudfront

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services

Looking to host multiple static web sites by pointing DNS to an Elastic Load Balancer and serving the content via Cloudfront.

Is this a plausible approach? Are there any gotchas we should look out for. How should we configure DNS for each site?

Appreciate any thoughts on this

Dom

Comment: I guess the question is better put as .. 

"is it possible to distribute traffic via ELB to Cloudfront instead of to EC2 instances ?"

Comment: If it is a static site, why not just use Cloudfront with S3?  Why involve ec2 and elb at all?

Comment: and ideal solution, however as far as I can tell the issue is a DNS one. YOu can create an alias for cloud front, but I don't think you can assign an a-record since the IP address will change..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Each ELB will have it's own public DNS.  You will [need a CNAME](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/ElasticLoadBalancing/latest/DeveloperGuide/index.html?US_SettingUpLoadBalancerHTTP.html) for your domains to map them to the ELB so that your users can get to your ELB like this: www.mysite.com.

CloudFront will push an S3 bucket to Amazon's edge network - putting that content closer to it's requesting user.  Your domain names shouldn't point directly to this content, however your site (on your EC2 instance) will consist of HTML files that reference your [CloudFront distribution](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/GettingStartedGuide/index.html?UsingService.html).

Now you'll have one or more servers processing requests and CloudFront serving the content.  Very plausible.

Best of luck.

Chad

Comment: Hi Chad

From what I've gathered from the ELB documentation it will only work with EC2 instances. Therefore we'll have to have at least one instance linked to the ELB. 

My goal was to try to offload all the content serving to cloudfront by reverse proxying cloudfront via ELB. But alas this does not look possible

Am now investigating using HAproxy or plain old Apache as a solution

Thanks for your comment

Answer (score 1):

You can point your ELB or EC2 instance to cloudfront and this will push your dynamic content closer to your users.

http://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2012/05/13/amazon-cloudfront-now-supports-dynamic-content/

Answer (score 0):

If the content is static it makes more sense to think in terms of CloudFront pointing at S3.

For Amazon S3 buckets configured to host static websites, you also have the option of creating an ‘Alias’ record that maps to your S3 website bucket. Alias records have two advantages: first, unlike CNAMEs, you can create an Alias record for your zone apex (e.g. example.com, instead of www.example.com), and second, queries to Alias records are free of charge.